# Converting excel time to R time format

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

When I am trying to convert csv time format into R time format using the below code, I get datetime format although i do not intend to do so.

Why and how can i avoid it?

```
bat2$or_time<-as.POSIXct(as.character(bob$Order_Time), format="%H:%M:%S")
```

[image]

Comment: There is no time-only class in base R. Take a look at package `chron`, it is implemented there.

Comment: Why don't you `paste` `Order_Date` and `Order_Time` together and convert that to POSIXct (which is a datetime class)?

Comment: I tried that did not work but the below method did.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a time class (see package chron), a datetime class (that seems to be more sensible), or do you merely want to reformat the string (as the answers assume)?

Answer (score 1):

This did the Trick!

```
bat1$or_time<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(bat1$Order_Time), format="%H:%M:%S")
bat1$or_time<-format(bob$or_time, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose your expression with `format( 'your expression',"%H:%M:%S")` like so :

```
format(as.POSIXct(as.character(bob$Order_Time), format="%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
```